# Android binding width and/or height of two elements in xml

Tags: android

Suppose there is an XML Layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/label_text_dark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="______h1_____"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_line"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
        android:layout_height="______h2_____"
        android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

which eventually results to this:
[image]

so the question: is there a way to bind h2 to h1 in xml (NOT PROGRAMMATICALLY) so whenever h1 changes h2 changes automatically.

what am I looking for should look similar to this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/v_line"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:layout_height="@+id/title.height"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

*android:layout_height="@+id/title.height"* (this of course not works)

NOTE: one of elements can also be outside of parent container, e.g. v_line can be outside of linear layout

[image: it can be even this way]

*thanks in advance*

Comment: is this necessery to use LInearLayout?? It can easily be done in RelativeLayout,,it can also be done in LinearLayout uwsing weights..

Comment: @Wasim: linear layout is not important here, the focus of the question is to bind two elements' sizes

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this-

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/label_text_dark"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Last" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/v_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/light_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So the solution is to disable baseline alignment for the container view when it is not useful for your application. Then setting the layout weight of each view to be equal.

Also I encourage you to check out this article - [shifty-baseline-alignment](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/10/shifty-baseline-alignment/).

Comment: what am I looking for is binding, not a solution for particular case, what if v_line is somewhere outside of linear layout?

Comment: Then you can use `android:layout_baselineAligned` and `android:layout_weight` properties. See my edit.

Comment: this wont work, how do you think h1 will be bound to h2 if they are in different containers ?

Comment: Check the link posted. You probably need that. It may help out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up this values:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/label_text_dark"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_line"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

Heigth of LinearLayout is correct.

Comment: I've tried that before posting question, this makes entire segment to take whole screen height, and even by changing values in other elements I can get something similar what I need but still it is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/label_text_dark"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_line"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
```

alignTop will resize your view as TextView height changes..Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using RelativweLayout..Fix the Width of Views as you want

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_medium" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:background="#119283"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/v_line"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title"
     android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
    android:background="#342748" />
```

Comment: please read whole question NOTE: one of elements can also be outside of parent container, e.g. v_line can be outside of linear layout

Comment: bro you can do any thin using relative layout...can you please explain using the image posted above, which area is TextView and which area is View..I cant understand what u are actually facing and what you actually want to do

Comment: I added new image, please take a look maybe it will explain the issue